# Undefined variable: $message for notification

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a notification for the user when there is a new message in a conversation.

For some reason, it says it is an undefined variable in the notification.

Here is the code:

MessageController.php

```php
$message = $conversation->messages()->create([
    'user_id' => auth()->id(),
    'body' => request('body'),
    'conversation_id' => request('conversation_id')
]);


// when a message is created, notify all users of the conversation

foreach ($message->conversation->users as $messageConversationUser) {
    //if (auth()->user()->id !== $message->user->id) {
        //dd($message);
        $messageConversationUser->notify(new YouHaveNewMessage($message));
    //} 
}
```

YouHaveNewMessage.php

```
class YouHaveNewMessage extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $message; 

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'message' => $message->user->name . ' left a new message in ' . $message->conversation->title,
            'link' => $this->message->path()
        ];
    }
}
```

I'm not really using what's happening -- it's returning the message on `dd()` but throws an *undefined variable error*. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I think you need to change `$message` variable to others, Because laravel automatically makes the `$message` variable available to all of your email templates

Comment: I did try $newMessage and $conversation, but it did not work, and I still get the error

Comment: are you sure $message->user->name is not $this->message->user->name in your toArray function?

Comment: Thanks Osama, I didn't refer to the object passed -- it was supposed to be $this->message->user->name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `YouHaveNewMessage` class , toArray() method there is $message variabe. Looks like you are using local scope, but there is no `$message` variable declared in this method.

You need to use it as $this->message

```
public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'message' => $this->message->user->name . ' left a new message in ' . $this->message->conversation->title,
            'link' => $this->message->path()
        ];
    }
```